# Inflating a fragment with newInstance and animations

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-animation

What is the equivalent of `fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations (android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);` when inflating a fragment using `MyFragment.newInstance()` in a ViewPager rather than using a FragmentTransaction and`New MyFragment()` ?

Please note that if I simply add `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` to the ViewPager in MainActivity.xml it successfully implements default animations but unfortunately the very first time I swap a parent fragment with a nested fragment it uses *both* the scroll *and* fade in animations. There seems to be some clash with the default animations in this case. See this behavior here:

http://sendvid.com/yuc3fapq

MyAdapter.java

```
/**
 *  PageFragmentListener for switching fragment.
 */
public PageFragmentListener mListener = new PageFragmentListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSwitchToNextFragment(final String id) {
        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(mFragment).commit();
        if (mFragment instanceof ItemListFragment){     
            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            arguments.putString(Constants.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);   
            // switch detail fragment
            mFragment = ItemOneDetailFragment.newInstance(mListener);   
            mFragment.setArguments(arguments);
        }else{      // DetailFragment
             // switch list fragment
            mFragment = ItemListFragment.newInstance(mListener); 
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();  // notify changes
    }
};

public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    mFragmentManager = fm;
    List<Fragment> fragments = fm.getFragments();
    if(fragments != null){
        for(Fragment f : fragments){
            if(f instanceof ItemListFragment || f instanceof ItemOneDetailFragment){
                mFragment = (BaseFragment) f;
            }
        }
    }
 }

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (position == 0)      // Tab-1
        return FragmentA.newInstance();

    if (position == 1)      // Tab-2
        return FragmentB.newInstance();

    if (position == 2) {    // Tab-3
        if (mFragment==null)    // first time => create list fragment
            mFragment = ItemListFragment.newInstance(mListener);

        return mFragment;
    }

    return null;
}
```

ItemListFragment.java

```
public static ItemListFragment newInstance(PageFragmentListener listener) {
    ItemListFragment fragment = new ItemListFragment();
    fragment.mListener = listener;
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false);
    initLayout(root);
    return root;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`newInstance()` has nothing to do with how you create a `FragmentTransaction`, it just helps you instantiate the `Fragment` and pass in parameters. It's also not a good idea to hardcode the logic of creating a `FragmentTransaction` inside the `Fragment`: at some point you'll possibly want to reuse it without animations.

Comment: newInstance() is a static system method that returns New MyFragment() by default, no? I'm also using a ViewPager, which calls MyFragment.newInstance(). At no point am I using FragmentTransaction so I'm wondering how to animate between _specific_ Fragments as done with setCustomAnimation() in this case.